# Golang gin get client IP in ipv4 only

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to get the IP address of the client when using `gin-gonic` but sometimes it gives me the IPv6 address which I don't want.

My current code looks like this:

```
web.POST("/path", func(c *gin.Context) {
    ipAddr := c.ClientIP() // sometimes ipv4, sometimes ipv6
```

How do I get only the IPv4 address?

For reference I'm only listening on IPv4 address:

```
server := &http.Server{
    Handler: router,
}
l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", cfg.Listen)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = server.Serve(l)
```

---

Here are examples of the IPv6 addresses I'm receiving:

```
2402:800:6371:2f72:xxxx:bf67:3689:95df
2001:44b8:2169:c800:xxxx:c80a:b134:cc40
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually an IPv6 address, or is it an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address? Are you using a load-balancer/reverse-proxy, or are the IPv6 clients coming through an http proxy?

Comment: @JimB not sure if clients are coming from a proxy but they are mostly from vietnam. I asked them to do a *whatismyip* search and it comes up with a ipv4 and ipv6 address. I also tried `net.ParseIP("2001:44b8:2169:c800:xxxx:c80a:b134:cc40").To4()` which returns nil.

Comment: OK, some remote clients have an IPv6 address. If you don't have a load balancer or reverse proxy in your service, then it's coming through another proxy somewhere. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JimB I only want to get the IPv4 address. Because I have another TCP server that is I want to compare IP addressees to and I can't because the website gets an v6 while the server gets a v4 address. So I want to get only IPv4 on the website too.

Comment: The IPv4 address of _what_? You either the want reported client address, which may be IPv6, because it is on the internet and you can't ignore that IPv6 exists; or you want the address of the tcp connection. If you only want the address of the remote _connection_, that's `Request.RemoteAddr`, but it's of course often not the original client IP address. (The docs for [`ClientIP`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ClientIP) should explain _why_ you're getting the IP your are)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but this below function helped me to get the IPAddress

```
func getClientIPByHeaders(req *http.Request) (ip string, err error) {

    // Client could be behid a Proxy, so Try Request Headers (X-Forwarder)
    ipSlice := []string{}

    ipSlice = append(ipSlice, req.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For"))
    ipSlice = append(ipSlice, req.Header.Get("x-forwarded-for"))
    ipSlice = append(ipSlice, req.Header.Get("X-FORWARDED-FOR"))

    for _, v := range ipSlice {
        log.Printf("debug: client request header check gives ip: %v", v)
        if v != "" {
            return v, nil
        }
    }
    err = errors.New("error: Could not find clients IP address from the Request Headers")
    return "", err

}
```